# Jenkins version as a pipeline variable?

Tags: jenkins

I'm using Jenkins ver. 2.138.3 for my builds, which typically are declarative pipelines.

For traceability reasons my build manifest will contain details such as BUILD_NUMBER, GIT_COMMIT which are global environment variables. I'm desperately missing the Jenkins version from that list of variables. Is there a way to get the Jenkins version from pipeline script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick from a Pipeline script:

```
Jenkins.instance.getVersion()
```

([API docs reference](https://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/jenkins/model/Jenkins.html#getVersion--))

Comment: Thanks! It works as long as not being sandboxed.